# How to transfer a file from unix server to windows pc

Tags: windows, file-transfer

Right now I am using winscp to manually copy files from unix server to my windows desktop.
I Would like to automate the same by running some script in unix.

Can someone please help?

-Sajith

Comment: The usual (first) answer is FTP. Where would you like to run your FTP server, Unix or Windows?

Comment: I need to run the scripts in unix. say source file path be /home/file.txt and target path C:\Windows\Desktop

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: run an FTP server on Windows and write a simple FTP client script on Unix.

For Windows, you can use

- IIS (built in to all versions of Windows, but switched off by default)
- Filezilla -- free https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server
- one of the many proprietary FTP server programs. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software

At the Unix end, write a script to control the built in FTP client.

Another answer is: use IIS on Windows as a file uploader/downloader by writing a really simple Web site. Use wget or curl at the Unix end.

Another answer is: implement SAMBA on Unix, so that it joins your local Windows network. Copy files using standard shell commands.

Another answer is: use Dropbox and transfer files via the cloud.

I could probably think of more, but that's enough.

Comment: What is the curl command to copy from Unix to a Windows FTP? Do you have any example?

Comment: @SenthilArumugamSP: No, I don't. Check the docs or ask a new question.